# How to get dlls out of web reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, k2

In my visual studio I am adding a web reference but now I want to get dll of web reference class, for example my web reference is called `myWebServiceClass`.

If i build my project out I get is `myWebServiceClass.asmx` but I want `myWebServiceClass.DLL`.

My work mate did it but he is on holidays for three weeks and am stuck. as K2 Black pearl workflow not recognising my web reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be in the same folder where you can see the .asmx file, normally It gets generated into the Bin folder.